# Passing user id from the WP session to another PHP session

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WP site with a membership plugin.

On this site I have a PHP script which runs in an iframe.

They are using the same database.

I need to pass the id of the user to that script so it can use the user data from the database, is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add the session_start in your wp-config.php, just before the call of the wp-settings:

`if (!session_id())
    session_start();`

Comment: Can you please expand on  that? how can I pass the id to the external script using this method? Thanks

Comment: well i do not know your script and how it works, but if it is on the same host as your wp site and it is bound trough an iframe, theoretically the PHPSESSID should be shared... in that case the session is started in your wp-config and tough accessible from any php script inside your site. just call "session_id()" within your script.

Comment: I put the following in the beginning of the external script "if (!session_id()){session_start();} $temp = session_id();" and got something... t3bf2pv10kr4bqn6eek7ftf2i2. Can I get the user id from that? Thanks again

Comment: session_start() suppose to resume the previous session right?